# dns error, no such host on google-container-engine

Tags: go, dns, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

we're trying to get Let's Encrypt up and running inside kubernetes with [kube-cert-manager](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kube-cert-manager).

When running `kube-cert-manager`[this function](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kube-cert-manager/blob/master/dns.go#L103) is called to monitor the dns propagation which checks if the ACME challenge is found inside the dns TXT record.
When this gets called this error gets logged.

```
 2016/09/05 12:52:47 monitorDNSProgragation error: lookup foo.bar.de on 10.71.240.10:53: no such host
```

`10.71.240.10` is the DNS server used everywhere inside our kubernetes cluster. I can resolve `foo.bar.de` in every container (pod) inside the cluster using `dig`. This is also possible in the `kube-cert-manger` container.
It's just not possible with the `kube-cert-manager` binary.

`kube-cert-manager` uses [github.com/miekg/dns](https://github.com/miekg/dns). I've replaced the function linked above with stdlib `net.LookupTXT(c.domain)` which returns the same error.

Is this some Go bug?
Some known configuration error in google-container-engine?

If you need more information just ask.

Thanks.